# How to distinct (count) value when value is nested in array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, group-by, aggregate, distinct

I have a data sample something like this:

```
"diagnostics" : {

    "_ID" : "554bbf7b761e06f02fef3561",

    "tests" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "59d678064e4645ec562a37e2",
            "name" : "RBC",
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "59d678064e4645ec562a37e1",
            "name" : "Calcium",
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to get all distinct _ID and count of all test groups in  with there names
which is something like this:

```
"_ID" : "554bbf7b761e06f02fef3561"{ {"name" : "Calcium", count :(count of Calcium)},{"name" : "RBC", count :(count of RBC)}
```

Thing to keep in mind are tests is inside diagnostics and contain any number of $name field it can be two or one or any number  of times and I want individual count of each distinct name .

```
db.collection('transactions').aggregate([
{ $unwind : '$diagnostics.tests' }, 
  {  $group : {
  _id: {
    "Test_Name" : '$diagnostics.tests.name',
    "ID" : '$diagnostics._id'
  },
  test_count: {  $sum: 1  } 
}
 }  
])
```

and I am getting result something like this

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "Test_Name": "Fasting Blood Sugar",
      "ID": "554bbf7b761e06f02fef3561"
    },
    "test_count": 76
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "Test_Name": "Fasting Blood Sugar",
      "ID": "566726c35dc18d13242fffcc"
    },
    "test_count": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "Test_Name": "CBC - 7 Part",
      "ID": "566726c35dc18d13242fffcc"
    },
    "test_count": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "Test_Name": "RBC",
      "ID": "554bbf7b761e06f02fef3561"
    },
    "test_count": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "Test_Name": "Fasting Blood Sugar",
      "ID": "5a2c9edfe0d0ec71aef1e526"
    },
    "test_count": 6
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "Test_Name": "Calcium",
      "ID": "554bbf7b761e06f02fef3561"
    },
    "test_count": 77
  }
]
```

Can anybody help me with the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use mulitple [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stages here.

First [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the tests and [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) it by "name" and then resize it to original and lastly then [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) by "diagnostics_ID" and for the tests count you can check the [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) of the "tests" array.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$diagnostics.tests" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "_id": "$diagnostics.tests.name",
      "diagnosticID": "$diagnostics._ID"
    },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "_ID": "$_id.diagnosticID"
    },
    "tests": {
      "$push": {
        "name": "$_id._id",
        "count": "$count"
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "diagnostics._ID": "$_id._ID",
    "diagnostics.tests": "$tests",
    "_id": 0,
    "testCount": { "$size": "$tests" }
  }}
])
```

[Code snippet](https://mongoplayground.net/p/U4a-gpuobRU)

Comment: Thankq for the answer

Comment: Sorry..this is my first question on stackoverflow